# Svelte framework: environment variables not appearing in svelte app

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, svelte, rollupjs

I'm trying to use environment variables in my svelte app. I've installed `@Rollup/plugin-replace` and `dotenv`. I created a `.env` file to hold my `API_KEY` and added the following to `plugins` in `rollup.config.js` from this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@firthous.dev/how-to-setup-env-variables-to-your-svelte-js-app-c1579430f032):

```
plugins: [
  replace({
    __myapp: JSON.stringify({
      env: {
        isProd: production,
        API_URL : process.env.API_URL
      }
    }),
  }),
]
```

and in the svelte components of my app I would access my API key via

```
const apiUrl = __myapp.env.API_URL
```

which worked. However, a few days later I was having authentication issues and after some debugging I found that `__myapp.env.API_URL` was returning `undefined` by trying to print it to the console.

I then tried changing the `replace` call to just `replace({'API_KEY': process.env.API_KEY})` and `console.log(API_KEY)` was still displaying `undefined`. I tested `replace` by trying to use it replace some variable with some string and it worked so that confirms that rollup is working fine. So, I suspect the problem is in `process.env.API_KEY` but I'm not sure. What might I be doing wrong with my attempts to access my environment variables?

(Some background: I am using [sveltejs/template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template) as a template to build my app)

Comment: i'm not familiar with svelte but gonna take a wild guess that maybe you only need to stringify the env variable values. so something like: `__myapp: { env: { isProd: JSON.stringify('production') } }`

Comment: @duxfox-- Hmm, just gave that a shot but did not work. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dotenv` won't register your `.env` vars until you call `config`, that's why `process.env.API_KEY` is undefined when you try to access it.

In your `rollup.config.js` you can do:

```
import { config as configDotenv } from 'dotenv';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';

configDotenv();

export default {
   input: 'src/main.js',
   ...
   plugins: [
    replace({
      __myapp: JSON.stringify({
        env: {
          isProd: production,
          API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
        },
      }),
    }),
    svelte({ ... })
   ]
}
```

Comment: production is not defined in rollup.config.js